# SQL 2 Subconsulta dentro de una variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Es posible introducir las siguientes subcosultas dentro de una variable ? (Precios de lista menor al promedio)

```
introducir el código aquí

select  ListPrice PrecioDeLista,
        (select avg(ListPrice) from Production.Product) Promedio
from    Production.Product
where   ListPrice < (
                    select avg(ListPrice)
                    from Production.Product
                )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento fallido de pasarlo a una variable

```
introducir el código aquí

declare @Promedio_promedio money = 0 
select @promedio_promedio =  (
                        select  ListPrice PRecioDeLista,
                                (select avg(ListPrice) from Production.Product) Prom
                        from    Production.Product
                        where   ListPrice < (select avg(ListPrice)
                                            from Production.Product
                                            )
)

select @Promedio_promedio
```

Me devuelve "Solo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS." Pero no se a qué se refiere exactamente ni como resolverlo.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista debes implementar un DTO para guardar el resultado en List de ese de DTO jeje

Comment: No puedes ingresar una lista de datos en una variable de valor escalar. ¿Qué intentarás hacer con la variable después? De eso dependerá la mejor opción para solucionar eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En una variable escalar no puedes meter múltiples datos. Para esto tienes que usar una variable tipo Table

```
Declare @table table (PrecioDeLista money, Promedio float);

Insert into @table (PrecioDeLista, Promedio)
select  ListPrice PrecioDeLista,
        (select avg(ListPrice) from Production.Product) Promedio
from    Production.Product
where   ListPrice < (
                    select avg(ListPrice)
                    from Production.Product
                );
```

A partir de ese punto, ya puedes usar la variable tipo Tabla como si fuera un conjunto. Pero siempre en la misma conexión.

Un ejemplo de lo que puedes hacer.

```
Select * 
  From @table t 
Where t.PrecioDeLista between 20 and 30;
```

[Variables tipo Tabla](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/16/variables-de-tabla/)